# Java Polymorphism: Accessing methods in super and subclasses

Tags: java, variables, object, reference, polymorphism

I'm somewhat confused in understanding how polymorphism actually works. At most, I understand that a superclass reference variable can refer to a subclass object reference, but I can't use that reference variable to access any of the subclasses fields and methods. Take for example this sample program:

```
public class Game
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Human hero = new Knight();
        hero.stats();
    }   
}

class Human
{
    public void stats()
    {
        System.out.println("HP: 10  STR: 25.");
    }   
}

class Knight extends Human
{   
    public void skill()
    {
        System.out.println("Sword master");
    }

    public void weapon()
    {
        System.out.println("Sword");
    }
}
```

From the sample program above, the only method I can call using the reference variable, hero, is the one declared within the class Human, but I have no access to any methods declared in the Knight class.

If I were to include the following whoAmI() method in both the Human and Knight class, the reference variable then refers to the subclass overriden method:

```
{...
       hero.whoAmI() // calls the method declared in the Knight class
    }

class Human
{       
    public void whoAmI()
    {
        System.out.println("Just a regular human");
    }
}

class Knight extends Human
{           
    public void whoAmI()
    {
        System.out.println("A mighty knight");
    }
}
```

While I do understand why the overriden method whoAmI() is called instead of the superclass' method, since the JVM (correct me if I'm wrong) sees that the reference variable contains a reference to a knight object, **why can't I access any of the methods declared within the Knight class using the reference variable?**

Answer (score 1):

```
Human hero = new Knight();
```

You defined your hero to be a class `Human`. Therefore, you will only inherit those properties that are available to its parent class.

If you define your hero as a `Knight`, then you will have access to both `Human` and `Knight` properties.

```
Knight hero = new Knight();
```

a few nitpicking: better declare your properties `private`, and use a getter/setter.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Because, it breaks the contract.

Let's assume (just to understand the why) that Java allows you to call a `Knignt` class method on a `Human` class reference and you publish a `public` method like

```
public void doHumanThings(Human being) {
  ...
  // but somewhere inside the method you call
  being.doKnightThings();
  ...
}
```

This breaks the contract because other classes can't simply pass a `Human` object like

```
Human onlyHuman = new Human();
someObj.doHumanThings(onlyHuman);
```

That's because if they do, your code breaks at runtime when calling

```
onlyHuman.doKnightThings(); // ERROR!
```

because **All `Human`s cannot be `Knight`s**.

So, although you've declared to the rest of the Java world classes (with a `public` method in a `public` class) that you expect a `Human` object, you're breaking the contract by expecting it to behave like a `Knight` *which the other client classes may not be even aware of*.

You can't simply assume that a `Human` reference will *always* point to a `Knight` object. The only way you can enforce that is by declaring the reference of type `Knight` itself.

However, if a method implementation wants to mostly make use of the parent class behaviour but add or adapt in case a subclass object is received, then an explicit downcast following an `instanceof` check can be performed as

```
public void doHumanThings(Human being) {
  being.doHumanThings();
  ...
  // Is this Human a Knight too?
  if (being instanceof Knight) {
    Knight iAmAKnightToo = (Knight) being;
    // OK. Using a Knight reference now.
    iAmAKnightToo.doKnightThings();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Think it this way

**Knight hero = new Human();
Why this is wrong ?**

Since accessible/visible methods depend on the **type of reference variable** hero.
So all child methods can be called **logically** but technically u are not holding the object of child class so u cannot call the child methods.

Similarly u are holding a base class reference 
Human hero = new Knight();

**The methods that are visible/accessible depends on the type of reference variable in which you are holding the object and not on the object.**

So if you change it to 
Knight hero = new Knight();
All the methods become accessible (base class and child class).

Answer (score 0):

> why can't I access any of the methods declared within the Knight class
>   using the reference variable

Because at compile time, compiler only knows about the reference used, so only methods available in the reference type class are available.

Poplymorphism is also called dynamic binding because it is decided at the run time depending on the object, which class method will be called.

Answer (score 0):

You can only access the methods from the type of the left side of the declaration. Java sees the object 'hero' as a Human not a knight. This helps with type safety in iterators and the like (more advanced than this question I think). This is a safety feature that ensures certain methods are implemented but can also be overridden or not.

So only the methods in the left hand declaration are available. It may seem annoying now but in more advanced polymorphic problems this is a very nice type safety.

Answer (score 0):

**Every class and every interface defines a contract**. Contract is defined by public methods (very simplified).

Contract means what methods you can call on the object extending a class or implementing an interface. If you store an object (Car) to a reference of different type (Vehicle):

```
Vehicle v = new Car();
```

You are basically saying treat the car as a vehicle. Once you say that you are using the contract of the Vehicle and not the car.

That means you can only call methods defined in the Vehicle and not the new ones in Car.

Comment: And that kind of programming is a bad practice?

Answer (score 0):

```
 Human hero = new Knight();
```

**Human** = Referance Type  ,  **hero**= Reference variable , 
**new Knight()** = Object Type

if you call a overriden method ; Object Type decides which method can be called.

if you call a non-overriden method ; Reference type decide which method can be called.